# Run multiple Select queries as batch/pipeline using Xorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-xorm

Can we run multiple select queries as a batch/pipeline using Xorm Engine in Go? I have a set of 5 queries and if any of them fails my whole logic should fail, but then if they succeed I need the output from all of them. So I want to save on the round trip time in running individually vs batch. Any way to achieve this using Xorm Engine in Go?

Comment: You have just described a "transaction". According to the documentation, Xorm does support transactions, but this also depends on the database you're using. Most do support transactions, but not all.

Comment: If I understand correctly, transaction is just a logical block. Round trips would still be 5 if I use transaction? I am using MySQL database

Comment: Yes, you still have multiple round trips. If you want to avoid that, you probably need to use a stored procedure. And at that point, `xorm` is probably all but irrelevant.

Comment: Got it thanks, will have to work with round trips then.